# Do same-year editorials contribute to impact factor?

Tags: citations, editors, bibliometrics

In many journals, original articles are accompanied by editorials.

It appears to me that these do not increase the impact factor directly, as same-year citations are not eligible for impact factor calculations (see [here](https://scholarlykitchen.sspnet.org/2020/12/07/jif-calculation-2021/) for further details):

[image]

Thus, they mainly increase indirectly the visibility of the journal and its works.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

For an *n* = 1 perspective: I serve on an editorial board for a journal was told *front matter* such as editorials and some types of perspective papers count for citations, but not number of articles.

Also, getting articles online early gives them more time to be "cited" before the time window closes for impact factors.

So, journals will try to optimize the system and publish high-impact editorials and perspectives.
Journals also like to get materials online quickly for impact factors (as well as better statistics for submitting authors).

**Note:** These rules always seemed nebulous to be and subject to change. Also, a cyclical person might question the gaming of the system by journals.

Sorry, I don't have any documents to support my observations.

Comment: An even more cynical person (cough) might worry that there is too much emphasis on impact factor by authors.

Comment: Yes. I would agree that most parties who care about the numbers are playing the system.